# jquery table can't elaborate well Chinese or any accented characters inside mysql table

Tags: mysql, encoding

I create a database called Country and and when I was importing data file I set utf8_general_ci for Collation.
[image: encoding1]

Before import sql file I check if code was set correctly for importing:

```
CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `iso` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `printable_name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `iso3` char(3) default NULL,
  `numcode` smallint(6) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=240 ;


INSERT INTO `country` VALUES (1, 'AF', 'AFGHANISTAN', 'Afghanistan', 'AFG', 4);
INSERT INTO `country` VALUES (2, 'AL', 'あなざ', 'Albania', 'ALB', 8);
INSERT INTO `country` VALUES (3, 'DZ', 'ALGERIA', 'Algeria', 'DZA', 12);
```

After importing I have this:

[image: encoding2]

You can see that Mysql Database encode correctly chinese characters:

[image: encoding good]

After type http://127.0.0.1/flexigrid/ Jquery-flexigrid table can't decode correctly chinese, russian or any accented characters inside mysql database.
I check also .php page and I set `<meta charset="utf-8">` for encoding chinese characters from .php page but my problem is a bad encoding from database to table.

[image: encoding3]

***What Can i Do?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your database connection is setted to `utf8` in your php file.

```
mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

Comment: try add `mysql_set_charset('utf8',$connect);` after line 8

Comment: BTW, you should close the database connection before return the `$result`, and php have a build-in function `json_encode()` for convert php array to json in string (but the json format should a bit different compare to your current code) :)